# Minimum Access_token require to fetch photos posted in a page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, token, photo, facebook-page

Playing with facebook graph, I'm wondering what is the minimum permission + access_type needed for accessing photo stream (source) published by someone on a page.

Currently trying to fetch :
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=152816981564783

I get the full result with the graphTool explorer, but I'm not able to get it with the facebook app I've developed.

If an admin post to the page, I can get the images or link, but if it is someone else (classir user, I do not get anything except the following error :

```
{ error:
{ message: 'A user access token is required to request this resource.',
 type: 'OAuthException',
 code: 102 } }
```

I've been trying to extend the app token but it still get the same response.

Authorization are manage_page, publish_stream

Any help would be much apreciate !

thanks

Comment: Just replaced the token I use with my app, and I get the same error. So question is :

How to programmatically fetch photos without user token and user login.

Comment: ...`user_photos`? don't get it.

Comment: Have you tried using App Access token to get the Post?

Comment: Do you changed anything? Currently https://graph.facebook.com/152816981564783 not require me to pass any access token.

Comment: Yes I did, that is why I get that I need a user access token. I get the post, the image is not accesible...

Comment: nop didn't change anything :( super weird.
Even : http://sphotos-f.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/s2048x2048/971278_152816981564783_1580177696_n.png is fully accessible...
Is that related to fresh post VS old post. Now it is like 16hours ago...